# ModuleNotFoundError when calling Python from system() in R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I have an Rscript on my Raspberry Pi that calls a Python script through system()
So let's say

tweetsomething.R

```
# first some data cleaning etc.

system("python3 tweetImage.py var1 var2")
```

This gives me a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'tweepy'
```

I checked the python paths and

```
which python3
```

gives me the same as

```
system("which python3")
```

which is

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

The python script works when called directly and it also works if I run R on my rpi and than run

```
system("python3 tweetImage.py var1 var2")
```

which is the strangest thing of all. So somehow the Rscript looks like the problem for getting to the library.

Because the python script needs variables from R, it needs to be called from R.

The same goes for

```
system2()
```

which works in R, but not in an Rscript.

Comment: is there a reason you're not using reticulate?

Comment: It won't install on my RPI model 3

Comment: fair enough! maybe another thing to put on SO as a question, as maybe it's possible to get it working, idk

Comment: another debugging idea: check the python location within the script(`import sys; print(sys.executable)`), then run using rscript and through R and through python directly

Comment: Besides the python executable, you also need to check that your script/subshell has access to the packages (i.e. `tweepy` in this case).  And packages are stored in more than one place depending on how you installed them (with `pip`, with `apt install`, inside a `venv`).  Some more ways to inspect: 1) compare `sys.path` from terminal vs from Rscript; 2) make sure the Location in `pip3 show tweepy` exists in the output from (1).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, a tiny test setup here (RPi4, not RPi3) seems to work ok as follows:

- RPI4, with python3.7
- `apt install r-base`
- `pip3 install tweepy`
- python script: `echo -e "import tweepy\nprint('ok')\nprint(tweepy.__file__)" > test_tweepy.py`

```py
import tweepy
print('ok')
print(tweepy.__file__)
```

- R test script: `echo -e "rv <- system('python3 test_tweepy.py')\nprint(rv)\n" >> test_py.R`

```
rv <- system('python3 test_tweepy.py')
print(rv)
```

Running the python script directly, and also via Rscript

```bash
$ python3 test_tweepy.py 
>>> ok
>>> /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py

$ Rscript test_py.R
>>> ok
>>> /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py
>>> [1] 0
```

shared
As I commented, python packages can be installed in multiple locations depending on the installer used (`pip`, `apt`, `sudo pip` all result in different install paths for example). So it is worth checking that your environment inside the Rscript subshell has access to the right one (or all).

Comment: I get exactly the same output as you.

Comment: @Lucius am I missing something in what you are trying to achieve? The 2nd test here, with `Rscript test_py.R` shows a working module load of `tweepy`, via Rscript. If that works for you, that seems to solve your problem.

Comment: good call. Maybe the problem is that I call the python script through an functionseveral scripts deep. Strange one, but you're right. This looks good